# help me create pagination file in config

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I want to create a pagination file in config folder to using for many pages.

But, i don't known how to set values of $config[], because they belong to data.

eg: $config['total_rows'] = ?  $config['base_url'] = ?

please..help me ! thanks !

Comment: You have to query the database to get total rows values before you make up your config settings. base url is your page url

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/site/big/';
    $where = "bot = '2' OR bot = '0'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('visitors');//query here for total rows
    $config['per_page'] = 15;
    //$config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

$this->db->order_by('date', 'DESC');
    $where = "bot = '2' OR bot = '0'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->select('id, ip, date, page, host, agent, spammer, country, total, refer');
    $data['records'] = $this->db->get('visitors', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->table->set_heading('Id', 'IP', 'Date', 'Page', 'Host', 'Agent', 'Spam', 'Country', 'Total', 'Referer');
    $this->load->view('site_view', $data);
```

Base url is your website url + the controller/function
Per page is how many rows you want to see on each page

Comment: thank for your reply ! but...'visitors' is table ? how to send dynamic value to $where variable ? Your codes can not use for many pages with data tables :(

Comment: Yes visitors is the table. The dynamic value would come from a form, a search or whatever, or explicitly defined like mine is $where = "bot = '2' OR bot = '0'"; This script works for 26 pages on my site.  I added the rest of the controller for you to see